# How to get the size of a site collection through C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, size, sitecollection

I have limited the size of the content database upto 200 GB. I have used the following code to get the size of a content database.

```
SPWebApplication elevatedWebApp = spWeb.Site.WebApplication;
SPContentDatabaseCollection dbCollection = elevatedWebApp.ContentDatabases;
//Guid id = dbCollection[0].Id;

Guid lastContentDbGuid = new Guid(contentDbGuid);
//SPContentDatabase lastDatabase = dbCollection[dbCollection.Count - 1]; 

SPContentDatabase lastDatabase = dbCollection[lastContentDbGuid];
ulong dbSize = lastDatabase.DiskSizeRequired;
contentDbMB = ConvertToMegabytes(dbSize);
```

> 

```
static string ConvertToMegabytes(ulong bytes)
{
    return ((decimal)bytes / 1024M / 1024M).ToString("F1") + "MB";
}
```

Similary I want to limit a site collection upto 100 GB. So I am using the following code

```
long bytes = spSite.Usage.Storage;
double siteCollectionSizeInMB = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(bytes);
```

>

```
static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}
```

I need the size of collection using C# only. Am I doing it right way ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me. If anyone is having different solution then please share.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0d066e9b-f6b9-49bc-b741-fcf7abdc854b

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two solutions here: [Theres both a powershell and c# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007180/how-to-find-size-of-the-content-database-in-moss-2007-and-no-of-site-collectins) i.e. the C# solution to get the collection size is:

```
SPWebService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>();
    foreach (SPWebApplication webapp in service.WebApplications)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WebApplication : " + webapp.Name);
        foreach (SPContentDatabase db in webapp.ContentDatabases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, Nb Sites : {1}, Size : {2}, ", db.Name, db.Sites.Count, db.DiskSizeRequired);
        }
    }
```

You could use the following to get the total DB size etc ([Taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.size%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

```
Server srv new Server();

Database db = srv.Databases("MyDatabase");

\\Display size and space information for the database.
Console.WriteLine("data space usage (KB): " + db.DataSpaceUsage.ToString);
Console.WriteLine("index space usage (KB): " + db.IndexSpaceUsage.ToString);
Console.WriteLine("space available (KB): " + db.SpaceAvailable.ToString);
Console.WriteLine("database size (MB): " + db.Size.ToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

C# uses essentially the same structure as Powershell in this case and a good example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.usage%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(http://yoursitehere.com/site)
{
    SPSite.UsageInfo usageInfo = site.UsageInfo;
    long storageReq = usageInfo.Storage;
}
```

If you need to iterate through each site in a content database, just call the content database object and reference its `.sites` property.